# Simulating Disk I/O

Tags: linux, storage, nas

We are currently evaluating storage for a virtualization environment (Xen). The storage is an active-active cluster and I need to test some stuff there like split brain scenarios etc.

I'm looking for a tool that simulates a lot of small disk I/O, like a virtual machine would read/write to its image file.

I don't need performance testing tools but more something like data integrity. Is there anything around?

Comment: If it's nix, then you could use a simple shell script with looped `sleep`s and `dd </dev/random >$(mktemp)` (you'll need mktemp package for generating temp random file names)

Comment: I don't get why you need to simulate anything. Create a loopback device, and run `fio` on it. Those are real world results.

Comment: `dd` does not verify data integrity. Also, it writes continuous to a file. In a typical VM image, data gets written pretty "random" because of the underlying file system.

Answer (score 2):

btest[1] is able to do such things, it can read/write in random/sequential and can also verify the data afterwards.

[1] http://sourceforge.net/projects/btest/